# Hinnant's short_alloc only on stack

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

I am trying to use Hinnant's short_alloc for allocating vectors on stack,
I am trying to remove the heap allocation completely. Now comes the problem where the developer uses push_back beyond the vector size. I am thinking of overriding the push_back function such that it checks if the capacity is reached, if yes then it will assert the error. As it is understood that STL functions are not meant to be overridden, What will be the better approach to achieve.

Comment: Use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead...

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need to inherit anything to override anything. An allocator is allowed to throw an exception in the `allocate` function. After all, it uses `::operator new` which will throw `std::bad_alloc` if it can't allocate memory. On my system it does: `__throw_length_error("allocator<T>::allocate(size_t n) 'n' exceeds maximum supported size")` as well..

So inside your `allocate` function, do:

`throw std::bad_alloc();`

Still.. I'm unclear as to why one wants a `stack` allocated `std::vector` when there are arrays.. But that's not my business.

Comment: Array doesn't keep track of the actual elements in it

Comment: I am working on a embedded systems project with 512KB - 1MB of RAM, we cannot afford to use dynamic memory allocation, If I want to use STL containers,then left only with array in this situation. while looking for a way to use other containers, I came across this allocator, looking for a way to avoid dynamic memory allocation at all and try to take advantage of the STL containers and algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

I used to be a pro on this allocator, however, it does require you to correctly deal with the arena.

As the vector with the allocator is a separate type from the regular vector, it doesn't play nice with existing APIs. Instead, I've recently switched to [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html) for the same behavior with less overhead:

- small_vector: similar to the allocator
- static_vector: only the stack part

Both containers contain the arena in the class itself and have decent support for copy and move.